# Is it possible to create recurring/subscription payment with Express Checkout js 4.0 + Rest API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm currently investigating whether or not it would be possible to use the recent version of Paypal Express Checkout (checkout.js v4) to add it as payment option for a website that has recurring donations.

I'm aware of the old [NVP/SOAP version](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/), which is currently flagged as deprecated.

I've checked through the (numerous) documentation pages on the new checkout, [starting here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/) and so forth.

I'm also aware of the [Billing Plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans) & Billing Agreement APIs.

I can find plenty of examples using the old NVP but not this combination.

Is it possible to do using these?

Are there any official(ish) examples of this?

Comment: did you get this working? I'm trying to do this as well.

Comment: @kspearrin client decided not to go ahead, thankfully.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the `TOKEN` from the NVP api with the javascript integration, by passing it back in the `payment()` call:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js">
</script>

<script>
    var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = 'https://my-store.com/paypal/create-payment';

    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'production', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

        payment: function() {
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function(data) {
                return data.token;
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.redirect();
        },

        onCancel: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.redirect();
        }

    }, '#paymentMethods');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input on this. The NVP is flagged as deprecated,  would this work with the REST api?

Comment: Also, do I have to redirect away from the page?

Comment: You can use the REST api, and you don't need to redirect -- you can run some other code in onAuthorize instead of redirecting

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to give it a spin then.

Comment: Ben, How you use the Paypal REST api?